# Failed host lookup from rest.coinapi.io

Tags: flutter, api, dart, bitcoin

I am trying to fetch network data from the coinAPI to get the exchange rate for 1btc to usd.. but after fetching the api and awaiting it in price screen so the ui will give the exchange rate... I get failed host lookup
[image: error returned in console]

This is the coin_data.dart file... contains the api and networking

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

const List<String> currenciesList = [
  'AUD',
  'BRL',
  'CAD',
  'CNY',
  'EUR',
  'GBP',
  'HKD',
  'IDR',
  'ILS',
  'INR',
  'JPY',
  'MXN',
  'NOK',
  'NZD',
  'PLN',
  'RON',
  'RUB',
  'SEK',
  'SGD',
  'USD',
  'ZAR'
];

const List<String> cryptoList = [
  'BTC',
  'ETH',
  'LTC',
];

const coinAPIUrl = 'https://rest.coinapi.io/v1/exchangerate';
const apiKey = 'APIKEY';

class CoinData {
  Future<dynamic> getCoinData() async {
    // http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse('$coinAPIUrl/BTC/USD?apikey=$apiKey'));
    http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse('$coinAPIUrl/BTC/USD?apikey=$apiKey'));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var decodedData = jsonDecode(response.body);

      var lastPrice = decodedData['rate'];

      return lastPrice;
    } else {
      print(response.statusCode);

      throw 'Problem with the get request';
    }
  }
}
```

This is the price_screen.dart file.. the actual UI and display of the exchange rate

```
import 'dart:io' show Platform;

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:ticker_bitcoin/coin_data.dart';

class PriceScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const PriceScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<PriceScreen> createState() => _PriceScreenState();
}

class _PriceScreenState extends State<PriceScreen> {
  late String selectedCurrency = 'USD';

  DropdownButton<String> androidDropdown() {
    List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> dropdownItems = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < currenciesList.length; i++) {
      String currency = currenciesList[i];

      var newItem = DropdownMenuItem(
        value: currency,
        child: Text(currency),
      );

      dropdownItems.add(newItem);
    }

    return DropdownButton(
      value: selectedCurrency,
      items: dropdownItems,
      onChanged: (value) {
        setState(() {
          selectedCurrency = value!;
        });
      },
    );
  }

  CupertinoPicker iOSPicker() {
    List<Text> pickerItems = [];
    for (String currency in currenciesList) {
      Text(currency);
      pickerItems.add(Text(currency));
    }

    return CupertinoPicker(
      itemExtent: 32.0,
      onSelectedItemChanged: (selectedIndex) {
        print(selectedIndex);
      },
      children: pickerItems,
    );
  }

  // Widget getPicker() {
  //   if (Platform.isIOS) {
  //     return iOSPicker();
  //   } else if (Platform.isAndroid) {
  //     return androidDropdown();
  //   }
  //   return getPicker();
  // }

  String bitcoinValueInUSD = '?';

  void getData() async {
    try {
      double data = await CoinData().getCoinData();
      setState(() {
        bitcoinValueInUSD = data.toStringAsFixed(0);
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text(' Coin Ticker'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(18.0, 18.0, 18.0, 0),
            child: Card(
              color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
              elevation: 5.0,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0, horizontal: 28.0),
                child: Text(
                  '1 BTC = $bitcoinValueInUSD USD',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 125.0,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30.0),
            color: Colors.lightBlue,
            child: Platform.isIOS ? iOSPicker() : androidDropdown(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: This is what I am getting]

[image: This is what is supposed to occur]

Comment: better hide this api key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means your device/emulator got disconnected to the internet. If your host is connected to internet but emulator is disconnected then a cold reboot will do the trick. You'll find that under **Device Manager** > **vertical ellipsis (⋮)** > **Cold Boot Now button**. [image: Here is an image]